# Can files be tampered with when obtained through JFileChooser?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, binary, jfilechooser

I'm trying to make my own binary editor. I have just gone through the tutorial on 
Netbeans on how to add the JFileChooser but can't figure out how to convert the txt file to binary through it. This is the code on the netbeans website.

```
private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    try {
      // What to do with the file, e.g. display it in a TextArea
      textarea.read( new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath() ), null );
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
}
}
```

How can I convert the file before it gets written to the text area?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by 'convert to binary'? A JTextArea can't display binary. Do you mean hex for example?

Comment: @EJP No, like the 0110001 stuff. How would I display it after inputting a file with say, a grocery list?